# Is it possible to override the "call" function?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to override the "call" function on a generic level, so that every time when a method gets called anywhere in the app, something happens.

I tried overriding Object.call, but although I managed to do it, it didn't change anything in the way my app works.

BTW, even if it works, should I explicitly call "foo.call(this,args)" every time, or normal function calls will also work "foo(args)" ?

Comment: Are you thinking of `Function.call`?  There is no method `call` on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you're really trying to accomplish.  I don't think you can intercept every javascript function call at the javascript level.  You'd probably have to have access to some hooks inside the JS engine to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do some kind of aspect oriented programming here....

JavaScript, as an ECMAScript dialect, does have the notion of a *callable object*.  Every callable object has an **internal property** called `[[Call]]`.  This property is described in Section 8.6.2, Table 9, of the ECMA-262 Specification, 5th edition.  It says:

> Executes code associated with the object. Invoked via a function call expression. The arguments to the SpecOp are a this object and a list containing the arguments passed to the function call expression. Objects that implement this internal method are callable. Only callable objects that are host objects may return Reference values.

But the thing to be aware of is that `[[Call]]` is an internal property, for which the spec says:

> An internal property has no name and is not directly accessible via ECMAScript language operators. Internal properties exist purely for specification purposes.

So you can not hook into this mechanism in your own JavaScript code.

Now there *are* two methods defined in `Function.prototype`, `apply` and `call`.  It is true that if you change the definition of `Function.prototype.call` then if you create your own function `f`, then `f.call` will indeed (unless overridden in f's prototype or in f itself) execute that code.  This will, as you presumed, NOT automatically happen by calling `f` directly.  You have to explicitly call the `call` method.

All that said, it is best not to muck with predefined, standard methods in the prototypes of built-in objects.  A lot of existing code in libraries and applications depend on `Function.prototype.call`.  Don't mess with it.  You can, of course, implement a kind of AOP behavior in many ways.  One is to add to `Function.prototype` some other method, **but don't do this either**.  Another is to write your own call method with before and after hooks:

```
function call(theThis, before, main, after, beforeArgs, mainArgs, afterArgs) {
    before.apply(theThis, beforeArgs);
    main.apply(theThis, mainArgs);
    after.apply(theThis. afterArgs);
}
```

Comment: I always cache a copy of the original call function and invoke that at the end

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you'd like to intercept any function call that is done your application? There's no way to do that, at least not on some generic level.