# Javascript closure and pre post function handlers

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

Regarding the question on SO [How to overload the calling process of any function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636597/how-to-overload-the-calling-process-of-any-function). The accepted answer is in fact not working as is. The problem lies in the fact the passed in variable "fn" is a string instead of a function. But if I changed fn() to NS[fn] (), it would create an infinite loop. Another way is to use a var inside the for loop to keep track of the old values of foo and bar, but it won't work too because of closure. I ended up adding a new array to keep track of the old functions as below:

```
NS = {
   foo : function(){ console.log('foo'); },
   bar : function(){ console.log('bar'); }
};

// <-- new code goes here

NS.foo();
NS.bar();

// new code below, that should go after definitions but before the calls

(function(){

   var pre = function(){ console.log('pre'); },
       post = function(){ console.log('post'); };

   var temp = new Array();//Added line 1

   for (var fn in NS) {
      temp[fn] = NS[fn];//Added line 2
     //original answer: NS[fn] = (function(fn){ return function(){ pre(); fn(); post(); }; })(fn);
      NS[fn] = (function(fn){ return function(){ pre(); temp[fn](); post(); }; })(fn);
   }

})();

NS.foo();//Added line 3
NS.bar();//Added line 4
```

My question is: are there other ways to do similar thing? I am not talking about a caller function as given by another answer to the quoted question. It is a good one. But I am just trying to find a different approach going the same way as the above given answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't passing the function into the anonymous block, you were just passing the name of the property holding it. Pass the whole function and it should work http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/bpq8j/

```
(function(){

   var pre = function(){ console.log('pre'); },
       post = function(){ console.log('post'); };

   for (var propName in NS) {
      NS[propName] = (function(fn){ 
        return function(){ 
          pre(); 
          fn(); // could be fn.call(NS) if you need 'this'
          post(); 
        }; 
      })(NS[propName]);
   }

})();
```

I changed your code slightly, abstracting the idea of pre/post into a function. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/bpq8j/1/

```
function addPrePost(fn, pre, post) {
    return function() {
      pre();
      fn();
      post();
    }
}

(function(){
   var pre = function(){ console.log('pre'); },
       post = function(){ console.log('post'); };
   for (var propName in NS) {
      NS[propName] = addPrePost(NS[propName], pre, post);
   }

})();
```